# Is it possible to start indexing of matrices from 1 in Eigen?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am using Eigen to do some linear algebra computations in my code. However, all of mathematical formulas are based on the fact that indexing starts from 1. So, each time that I want to implement them in the code, I have to check if my indexing in the code is consistent with them or not. I was wondering that if it is possible to tell Eigen to start the indexing from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to configure an eigen matrix like such. You could write a wrapper class containing an eigen matrix member variable though, and rewrite all indexing operations to adjust the indexing range. Though I don't think it's really worth it, and would confuse anyone else working with that wrapper.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thanks for the attention. Why they just insist on starting from zero?

Comment: _"Why they just insist on starting from zero?"_ Because in c++ it is the usual behavior for any containers that indexing starts at zero.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But Eigen is written to implement math and in math indexing usually starts from 1. Do you think that it take a lot of effort to make this possible for the users?

Comment: You probably want to ask that at a eigen specific forum, where their implementation details are discussed.

Comment: Indexing operations in Eigen allow, in addition to indexing with integers, indexing with symbolic indices. You should be able implement your own custom [symbolic index](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/SymbolicIndex_8h_source.html), derived from [`Eigen::symbolic::BaseExpr`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1symbolic_1_1BaseExpr.html), e.g. `MyIndexExpr` which can be used as a 1-based index API, where its `eval_impl` method simply subtracts `1` from its arg. E.g. `template<typename T> Index eval_impl(const T& values) const { return m_arg0.eval_impl(values) - 1; }`.

Comment: This would most likely be a very bad idea though, likely to lead to confusion, possible bugs as well as an extra non-motivated run-time overhead for any indexing. As you are coding in C++, you might want to stick to its zero-based indexing practice. Maybe you could consider symbolic indexing for when writing tests for your formulas, but using integer zero-based indexing for your product code.

Comment: @dfri: Thanks for the attention. I will appreciate it if you write your comments in a single answer. thank you very much. :)

Comment: @H.R. Happy to help. I combined my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing operations in Eigen allow, in addition to indexing with integers, indexing with symbolic indices. You should be able implement your own custom [symbolic index](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/SymbolicIndex_8h_source.html), derived from [`Eigen::symbolic::BaseExpr`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1symbolic_1_1BaseExpr.html), that could be used as a 1-based index API, where its `eval_impl` method simply subtracts `1` from its arg. E.g.:

```
template<typename Arg0>
class MyIndexExpr : public BaseExpr<MyIndexExpr<Arg0> >
{
public:
  MyIndexExpr(const Arg0& arg0) : m_arg0(arg0) {}

  template<typename T>
  Index eval_impl(const T& values) const { return m_arg0.eval_impl(values) - 1; }
protected:
  Arg0 m_arg0;
};
```

To use this in product code, however, would most likely be a very bad idea, likely to lead to confusion, possible bugs as well as an extra non-motivated run-time overhead for any indexing. As you are coding in C++, you might want to stick to its zero-based indexing practice. Maybe you could consider symbolic indexing for when writing tests for your formulas, but using integer zero-based indexing for your product code.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "not really".

Of course, as @πάνταῥεῖ suggested, you could write a wrapper or inherit from Eigen types and overwrite the indexing operators accordingly. Alternatively, you could implement a custom `Index` type which, when converted to `Eigen::Index`, will subtract 1.

But both approaches are error-prone and will likely rather increase confusion, especially if you miss some relevant parts. Also it will extremely confuse any C++ programmer looking at your code, as 0-based indexing is the most natural way in C/C++ (and many languages whose syntax is derived from them, like Java, C#, ...)

Finally, (as also suggested by @dfri) if you code in C++ get used to 0-based indexing, this will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.